# how to get the input value of a submitted form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have the bellow 'html' code:

```
<div class="userbox" id="'.$data[0]->id.'">
    <form action="schedule.php?page=management&ajax=true" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $data[0]->id .'" class="id">
        <input type="submit" name="remove_entry" value="x" class="ajax_btn">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the bellow JS code:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {

    $('.userbox form').on('submit',  function(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();


        var idVal = $('.id').val();

        alert(idVal);

        $.post("schedule.php?page=management&ajax=true", { id : idVal }, function (data) {
            $("#" + idVal + ".userbox").remove();
            $("#" + idVal + ".user_data").css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');

        }
    );

    });

});
```

I'm trying to get the value of the id from the form (taking in consideration there are multiple forms on page) but it's grabbing the first id on page instead of the one from the submitted form. Do you guys have any suggestions ?

Comment: Instead of just `$(.id).val`, you'd need to search based on WHICH form caused the submit, so `$(this).find('.id').val()` instead might do the trick.

Comment: Are your ids unique among the forms, or are they duplicated?  Also, why are you encoding items in the submission; why not put the values in hidden fields?

Comment: All id's are unique,as for the 'ajax' GET variable, that's only intended to check if the php page was accessed via 'ajax' or not. Marc's suggestion worked great. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You can check for AJAX or not by looking for the header `Requested-With` or `X-Requested-With` and if present check to see if it has the value `XMLHttpRequest` (warning: not a standard (yet))

Answer (score 1):

The query selector you use ($('.id')) is searching the whole document for nodes with the class "id" and is not limited to the submitted form.

Try to define your scope and search inside like this:

```
$('.userbox form').on('submit',  function(ev) {
    var scope = $(this);

    var idVal = scope.find('.id').val();
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the input by its name

```
var idVal = $(this).find( "input[name*='id']" ).val();
```